# Jquery code for multi-level dropdown navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

All,

I am new to JQuery and trying to write JQuery code to create a multi level dropdown menu. The HTML looks like below:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1.1</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#"> Sub Link 1.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Sub Link 1.1.2</a></li> 
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1.2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1.3</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2.1</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#"> Sub Link 2.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Sub Link 2.1.2</a></li> 
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2.2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The JQuery code I got so far is as under, but it's not opening and closing the submenus.How can I make it work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ul.menu > li').hover(function () { $('ul:first', this).show(); },
                           function () { $('ul:first', this).hide(); }
    );
    $('#ul.menu li li').hover(function () {
        $('ul:first', this).each(function () {
            var p = $(this).parent();
            $(this).css('top', p.position().top)
                   .css('left', p.position().left + p.width())
                   .show();
        });},
        function () { $('ul:first', this).hide(); }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chick this out: http://jsfiddle.net/g5xSX/ , maybe it is exactly what you want

Comment: This seems to work very nicely.. However, I want to introduce a delay of 1 second before a submenu item or the menu hides. How do i do that?

Comment: You may add a numeric parameter to `hide` every function like `hide(1000)` - it will specify duration of the hide effect and make it smooth

Comment: It is adding the delay, but not quite in a usable fashion. I wanted to add a delay similiar to the functionality of the menu in this link.. Is this possible?  http://javascript-array.com/scripts/multi_level_drop_down_menu/?st

Answer (score 0):

I created this fiddle, it's just a start but some of it it's working http://jsfiddle.net/mZzqu/2/

I simplified your markup (attach click handler to 'li', it's better)

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>Link 1
       <ul class="submenu">
         <li>Sub Link 1.1
           <ul class="submenu">
              <li id='1'> Sub Link 1.1.1</li>
              <li>Sub Link 1.1.2</li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Sub Link 1.2</li>
         <li>Sub Link 1.3</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Link 2
       <ul class="submenu">
         <li>Sub Link 2.1
           <ul class="submenu">
              <li> Sub Link 2.1.1</li>
              <li> Sub Link 2.1.2</li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Sub Link 2.2</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

jquery code

```
$.fn.dropdown = function (options) {
  var settings = jQuery.extend({
    timeout: 0.2
  }, options);
  var closetimer = null;
  var ddmenuitem = null;
    $(this).children('li').each(function(){
       $(this).find('ul').hide();
    });
  $(this).find('li').hover(dropdown_open, dropdown_close);
  document.onclick = dropdown_close;

  function dropdown_open(event)
  {
    dropdown_canceltimer();
    //dropdown_close();
    ddmenuitem = $(event.target).children('ul').css('display', 'block');
  }

  function dropdown_close(event) {
      $(event.target).parent('ul:not(#menu)').hide();
  }

  function dropdown_timer() {
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(dropdown_close, settings.timeout * 1000);
  }

  function dropdown_canceltimer() {
    if (closetimer) {
      window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;
    }
  }

  return this;
}
```