# JQuery slideToggle, collapse the child elements

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a menu with collapsible sub menu's, there are 3 levels of menu and it works fine but i don't know how to collapse all child sub levels when you click to collapse the parent one.

The way it works is that if you click level 1 it expands level 2, then if you click level 2 it expands level 3.

The issue is that when all levels are open, I need to be able to click level 1 and collapse both level 2 and 3 together. I am using slideToggle at the moment.

I have pasted my code below and I know it's a really rubbish way to do it but I have had to assign fake H tags to the menu items because it is generated by the ASP:Menu control and it gives no unique ID to the menu items so I had to find a way around it.

HTML:

```
<div id="Div1" class="MenuBar">
    <a href="#Menu1_SkipLink" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: auto; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;">Skip Navigation Links</a>
    <div class="mainmenu" id="Div2">
        <ul class="level1">
            <li><a class="level1 staticItem level1">
                <img src="/images/calculator.png" alt="" title="" class="icon" /><h7>Financial</h7></a></li>
            <li><a class="level2 staticItem level2">
                <h10>Address</h10>
            </a></li>
            <li><a class="level3 staticItem level3" href="javascript:openNewWin(&#39;/Controls/Financial/AddressBook.aspx&#39;)">
                <h11>Address Book</h11>
            </a></li>
            <li><a class="level3 staticItem level3" href="javascript:openNewWin(&#39;/Controls/Financial/CustomerTypes.aspx&#39;)">
                <h12>Customer Types</h12>
            </a></li>
            <li><a class="level1 staticItem level1">
                <img src="/images/container.png" alt="" title="" class="icon" /><h8>Container</h8></a></li>
            <li><a class="level2 staticItem level2">
                <h13>Containers</h13>
            </a></li>
            <li><a class="level1 staticItem level1">
                <img src="/images/product.png" alt="" title="" class="icon" /><h9>Product</h9></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a id="Menu1_SkipLink"></a>

</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    //When opening the page all level 2 and level 3 items must be hidden.
    $(function () {
        hideitems();
    })

    function hideitems() {
        $('h10').slideUp();
        $('h11').slideUp();
        $('h12').slideUp();
        $('h13').slideUp();
    }
    //Financial Click
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('h7').click(function () {
            $('h10').slideToggle();

        });
    });
    //Address Click
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('h10').click(function () {
        $('h11').slideToggle();
        $('h12').slideToggle();
    });
})
});
```

Any suggestions on how to collapse all sub levels would be greatly appreciated as I am no master of JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery code for multi-level dropdown navigation menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623179/jquery-code-for-multi-level-dropdown-navigation-menu)

Comment: The difference is that I can't modify anything in the UL, that includes giving classes or an ID.

Comment: That sounds too bad because the markup generator is so unaware of the fundamentals of HTML.

Comment: Yes you're right. I have tried lots of ways of creating the menu and the ASP:menu got me the closest. I am almost there but this is just the last thing I need to do in order for it to work properly.

Comment: Well, creating nested elements only requires 2/3 simple for loops + an array/object. there is no need to use third party tools.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the markup : build a structure which links subitems to items, and use it in the `.click()` callback.

For example, you can use `$(...).data` to associate data with a node :

```
// init function :
// we stack all level2 and level3 items as subitems of the last level1 item we met
// we stack all level3 items as subitems of the last level2 item we met
function init() {
    var $menu = $('ul.level1');
    var lv1Itm = null,
        lv2Itm = null;
    $menu.find('a').each(function () {
        var subitems;
        var li = $(this).closest('li').get(0);
        if ($(this).hasClass('level1')) {
            lv1Itm = li;
            $(li).data('subitems', []);
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('level2')) {
            lv2Itm = li;
            $(li).data('subitems', []);

            $(lv1Itm).data('subitems').push(li);
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('level3')) {
            $(lv1Itm).data('subitems').push(li);
            $(lv2Itm).data('subitems').push(li);
        }
    });
}
init();

$('.level1').click(function (e) {
    var subitems = $(this).closest('li').data('subitems');
    var shouldHideSubmenus = $(subitems).is(':visible');
    if (shouldHideSubmenus) {
        // in this case, hide all 'li' children items
        $(subitems).slideUp();
    } else {
        // in this case, only show level2 items
        $(subitems).find('.level2').closest('li').slideDown();
    }
});

$('.level2').click(function (e) {
    var subitems = $(this).closest('li').data('subitems');
    var shouldHideSubmenus = $(subitems).is(':visible');
    if (shouldHideSubmenus) {
        // in this case, hide all 'li' children items
        $(subitems).slideUp();
    } else {
        // in this case, only show level3 items
        $(subitems).find('.level3').closest('li').slideDown();
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ggN7z/4/)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, are you able to give an example? bearing in mind I can only change the text of the menu levels and nothing else.

Comment: As I said, I can't modify the markup at all, other than the text. It is generated by the ASP:menu control so I have to make use of what I have.

Comment: Is there a way to have the sub menus collapsed when the page first loads?

Comment: Yes, add according code ... `$('.level2, .level3').closest('li').hide()` should work

Comment: OK thanks for doing that, I tried the code in replacement of what I was using previously and it didnt have any effect on the screen elements when clicking. Is there anything more I need to do for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/B8b4z/1/

```
//Financial Click
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('h7').click(function () {
       $('h10').slideToggle(); 
       $('h11').slideUp("fast");
       $('h12').slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: What is .title .content etc.?

Comment: I created one, it's not great but if you use financial as an example it will give you an idea of the problem. Expand financial then address and then click financial again. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=E1Rmk0AHwi

Comment: plz check your link jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=E1Rmk0AHwi